# login_hint parameter of Google OAuth does not work in Safari user agent

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, safari, google-oauth

Users who have been approved by Google's OAuth will use login_hint to skip display the authentication screen from the next time.

Document: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow

But, Since few months ago, even if I use login_hint on the OAuth authentication screen, it no longer skips authentication.

This issue only occurs with Safari user agents.
You can check the problem at the following like URL.

[https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback&scope=openid&response_type=token&prompt=none&login_hint={email-address}](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=%7Bclient-id%7D&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcallback&scope=openid&response_type=token&prompt=none&login_hint=%7Bemail-address%7D)

Has anyone experienced the same problem and how did you address the issue?